# Is it possible to download and install 'chkdsk' for Windows 10 onto a bootable USB?

Tags: windows-10, bootable-media, chkdsk

**I have spent over an hour trying to locate a publicly-available site to download and install `chkdsk` onto a bootable USB.**

I was surprised to find no site where this is possible (at least from my initial attempt).

Is it possible to download and install `chkdsk` for Windows 10 from a publicly-available site onto a bootable USB?

Comment: maybe you can download an iso of so-called windows xp mode, which i understand is a win xp you can run in a virtual machine.  All windows post 98, is NT rather than the 9x family. And the command may be compatible.  I don't know if it is identical though

Comment: Any Windows Recovery Environment image has this tool

Comment: AT Ramhound worth noting whether there is a free one or not

Comment: @Ramhound I would have to dig up my Windows Recovery Environment image.  I would need to contact the company from whom I purchased my computer (Origin PC) and they are fully non-responsive - they literally do not follow up on any customer support they say they will do.  (Hence my question here - they said they would send me an email with a link to an installer for a bootable USB with `chkdsk`, but like a number of times before, I have received no email and I wish to find a way to do this without depending on them.)

Comment: Just download the current Windows 10 ISO?

Answer (score 1):

1. A similar question has been answered here: [How to run chkdsk if I can't boot to Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/193899/how-to-run-chkdsk-if-i-cant-boot-to-windows) . Basically, [download a copy of Windows Vista [or later] Recovery disk](http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/), which has CHKDSK.
2. Use a Windows PE ISO with CHKDSK, such as [Gandalf's Windows 10PE x64](http://windowsmatters.com/). See [5 Different Ways to Run Windows Check Disk (ChkDsk)](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/running-a-check-disk-with-an-easy-to-use-interface/).
3. [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) has a number of disk testing, partitioning and formatting tools, though not specifically CHKDSK.